# Python OOP, how to keep adding a number Instance attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Trying to deposit into the wallet, it worked the first call, then when I call the deposit function again it would give me the error.
`TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`
Any solutions to this?

```
class Bank():

    def __init__(self,wallet):
        self.wallet = wallet

    def withdraw(self,withdraw):
        self.withdraw = withdraw

    def deposit(self, deposit):
        self.deposit = deposit
        self.wallet += self.deposit




bank = Bank(0)

bank.deposit(500)
print(bank.wallet)
bank.deposit(500)
print(bank.wallet)
```

Comment: Why did you do `self.deposit = deposit`? Once you've done that `bank.deposit` is not a method any more, it's an int.

Comment: I was assuming that each time I create a function in a class that I would need to the self. for each variable.

Comment: You see lines like that in `__init__` methods frequently because `__init__` is where you define all the attributes of an object, but you usually don't want to set new attributes outside of `__init__`, nor do all the attributes set in `__init__` need to be 1:1 with the function arguments.  For example, your `Bank.__init__` could just always set `self.wallet = 0` to start with and not require a `wallet` argument at all.

Comment: Ah, okay I'll keep a note of that, thank you very much for clarifying this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reassigning your deposit function to an integer in the line.       `self.deposit = deposit`. Remove that :)

Comment: With the same logic, remove `self.withdraw = withdraw`.